# realloc implementation without memcpy

Tags: c, realloc, memcpy

can you please check this code to see why my implementation of a realloc function without using memcpy doesn't work? I am trying to figure out a way to transfer the payload size and tags from one block to another block. I got an invalid pointer error when i tried to run this code.

How do I transfer payload from one block to another without using memcpy or any other native c memory copy functions.

```
void* realloc(void* ptr, size_t size) {
  BlockInfo * oldBlockInfo;
  BlockInfo* newBlockInfo;
  size_t ptrSize;
  void* newPtr;
  if(ptr == NULL){
    return malloc(size);
  }
  else{
    if(size == 0){
        free(ptr);
        return NULL;
    }
  }
  oldBlockInfo = (BlockInfo*) UNSCALED_POINTER_SUB(ptr, WORD_SIZE);
  ptrSize = SIZE(oldBlockInfo->sizeAndTags); //getting the size of the old block
  //checking size
  if (ptrSize >= size){//if old size is greater or equal return old pointer
    return ptr;
  }
  else{
    newPtr = malloc(size);
    newBlockInfo = (BlockInfo*)UNSCALED_POINTER_ADD(newPtr,WORD_SIZE); 
    ptrSize = SIZE(newBlockInfo->sizeAndTags);
    for (int i = WORD_SIZE;i<ptrSize;i+=WORD_SIZE){
      newBlockInfo ->sizeAndTags = oldBlockInfo ->sizeAndTags;
      newBlockInfo = newBlockInfo ->next;
      oldBlockInfo = oldBlockInfo ->next;
    }
  }
  //examine_heap();
  free(ptr);
  return newPtr;
}
```

this is an implementation of realloc with memcpy, but I can't use memcpy

```
void *mm_realloc (void *ptr, size_t size) {
    int minsize;
    void *newptr;

    // Allocate new block, returning NULL if not possible.

    newptr = malloc (size);
    if (newptr == NULL) return NULL;

    // Don't copy/free original block if it was NULL.

    if (ptr != NULL) {
        // Get size to copy - mm_getsize must give you the size of the current block.
        // But, if new size is smaller, only copy that much. Many implementations
        // actually reserve the 16 bytes in front of the memory to store this info, e.g.,
        // +--------+--------------------------------+
        // | Header | Your data                      |
        // +--------+--------------------------------+
        //           ^
        //           +--- this is your pointer.
        // <- This is the memory actually allocated ->

        minsize = mm_getsize (ptr);
        if (size < minsize)
           minsize = size;

        // Copy the memory, free the old block and return the new block.

        memcpy (newptr, ptr, minsize);
        free (ptr)
    }

    return newptr;
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Why do you have `return 0;` after the comment that says "return old pointer"?

Comment: Why do you need to copy the tags to the new block? `malloc()` sets the proper tags in the new block. You should just copy the payload.

Comment: The loop should only copy the size of the old block, not the new block.

Comment: that's a good point. but I'm new to c, how do I separate the payload from the block.

Comment: Killerbee, Why `int` with `int minsize;` and not `size_t` like `size_t size`?

Comment: Why do you use `UNSCALED_POINTER_SUB()` with `ptr`, but `UNSCALED_POINTER_ADD()` with `newPtr`?

Comment: that's the way they implemented it, the bottom code is not mine. I am just trying to approximate what they did in the bottom code, without using memcpy. so my basic question is how do I transfer payload from one block to another, without using memcpy or any other native c memory copy functions.

Comment: If everything works with `memcpy`, then just write your own `memcpy` and call it, um, `not_literally_memcpy()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy just the payload of the old block into the new block. So don't overwrite `ptrSize` with the information about the new block, you need the old block's size. Subtract `WORD_SIZE` from it because you're not copying the header, since that was filled in properly by `malloc()`.

```
    newPtr = malloc(size);
    ptrSize -= WORD_SIZE; // subtract the header size
    char *tempPtr = newPtr;
    for (int i = 0; i<ptrSize; i++){
      tempPtr[i] = ptr[i];
    }
```

Comment: I get an invalid use of void expression when I try to do that.

Comment: I don't know what your macros like `WORD_SIZE` and `UNSCALED_POINTER_ADD` do, I had to guess how they can be used.